# Spliiting rows by intervals pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data

```
Start  End    Length            Number of Sections
0.01   0.03    0.02(End- Start)    0.02/0.01=2.0
0.00   0.05    0.05                0.05/0.01=5.0
```

I want my output to be

```
Start End      Length           Number of Sections
0.01  0.02      0.01              1.0
0.02  0.03       0.01              1.0
0.00  0.01       0.01               1.0
0.01  0.02       0.01                1.0
0.02  0.03       0.01                 1.0
0.03  0.04       0.01                  1.0
0.04  0.05       0.01                   1.0
```

Have tried many times.Kindly give some suggestions

```
bounds=np.unique(np.hstack((df["StartMilepost"],df["EndMilepost"])))

df2=pd.DataFrame({"StartMilepost":bounds[:-1],"EndMilepost":bounds[1:]})

isin=df.apply(lambda x :
              df2['StartMilepost'].between(int(x[0],x[1]-1)) 

              | df2['EndMilepost'].between(int(x[0]+1,x[1]),axis=1)).T

data=np.where(isin,df.NumberofSections,0)

df3=pd.DataFrame(data,
pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.values.T),df["min"])
```

Comment: So basically you want to construct a dataframe from the columns `Start` and `End`? The other two columns are simple calculations (in fact the number of sections are always going to be 1).

Comment: yup.The number of times we are going to divide a row depends on length/0.01.and start and end columns are already in the dataframe.just to manipulate my dataframe.